# Rails establishing frequencies of uniq values and limiting result

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With the following

```
@items.group(:nature_id).count(:nature_id)
```

one obtains a hash of results

```
{4=>1, 8=>1, 14=>2, 27=>1, 32=>1, 33=>1, 36=>1, 41=>2, 44=>1, 63=>1, 64=>4, 69=>1, 130=>7, 131=>3,[...]}
```

How can this result be sorted by the count value in decreasing order of said value & the result limited to 100 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
@items.group(:nature_id).order('COUNT(nature_id) DESC').limit(100).count(:nature_id)
```

**order('COUNT(nature_id) DESC')** - Will order the result by the count

> Also, syntaxically, this non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails
>   6.0.

According this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717592/dangerous-query-method-deprecation-warning-on-rails-5-2-3?noredirect=1#comment100013222_56717592) `COUNT(nature_id) DESC` doesn't going include any user input for SQL injection we need to explicitly bypass it with the below:

```
@items.group(:nature_id).order(Arel.sql('COUNT(nature_id) DESC')).limit(100).count(:nature_id)
```

Comment: That is returning the same hash as that in the question...  Also, syntaxically, this non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0.

Comment: Actually, examining the generated sql, @items was already ordered in a previous statement, this one simply regenerated the ordering filter.  The syntax that got it through required removal of the order in upstream command then `@items.group(:nature_id).order(count_nature_id: :desc).limit(100).count(:nature_id)`